# Deriving temperature in Blundell. How to determine the equality $\frac{d\ln(\omega_1)}{dE_1} = \frac{d\ln(\omega_2)}{dE_2}$?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

For two systems with Energies $E_1$, $E_2$ that can only exchange Energy with each other and that have $\omega_i(E_i)$ microstates I derive that:
$$\frac {d}{dE_1} (\omega_1(E_1) \omega_2(E_2)) = 0$$
$$\frac{1}{\omega_1} \frac{d\omega_1}{dE_1} - \frac{1}{\omega_2} \frac{d\omega_2}{dE_2} = 0$$
According to Blundell I can derive $$\frac{d\ln(\omega_1)}{dE_1} = \frac{d\ln(\omega_2)}{dE_2}$$ however I do not see how.

Comment: Differentiate the equation from Blundell by applying chain rule and it will reduce to the equation you derived.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally we have
$$\frac{d}{dx}\ln f(x)=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$$
so in this case
$$\frac{d}{dE}\ln \omega=\frac{1}{\omega}\frac{d\omega}{dE}$$
which is exactly what is in the equation:
$$\frac{1}{\omega_1} \frac{d\omega_1}{dE_1} - \frac{1}{\omega_2} \frac{d\omega_2}{dE_2} = 0 \iff \frac{1}{\omega_1} \frac{d\omega_1}{dE_1} = \frac{1}{\omega_2} \frac{d\omega_2}{dE_2}$$
so we can switch to
$$\frac{d\ln(\omega_1)}{dE_1} = \frac{d\ln(\omega_2)}{dE_2}$$
as done by Blundell

Comment: I would say that your first formula should be $\frac{d}{dx}\log f(x)=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$.

Comment: you are right, I corrected it now. I also put ln instead of log for consistency